# Equivalent of svn's blame for Perforce

Tags: svn, version-control, perforce

Is there an equivalent of svn's blame for Perforce on the command line? `p4 annotate` doesn't display usernames -- only changeset numbers (without ancestor history!).

I currently have to track code back through ancestors and compare against the filelog, and there just has to be an easier way -- maybe a F/OSS utility?

Comment: This is a vital feature. Git and Subversion can do it. Made a feature request to Perforce devs http://www.p4ideax.com/ideas/11922/add-a-command-p4-blame-similar-to-git-blame

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try taking a look at a couple of tools that I think could get you most of what you need:

1) [p4pr](https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/jonathan_kamens/p4pr.perl) Perl script by Bob Sidebotham and Jonathan Kamens.

2) [Emacs Perforce](http://www.dsmit.com/p4/) interface has a command 'p4-print-with-rev-history' (bound to `C-x p V').

Answer (score 58):

I'm not overly familiar with the blame command, but I assume that you are looking for who changes a particular line of code.  The easiest way is to use Perforce's 'time lapse view' available from both p4win and p4v.

This tool uses annotate and some other commands to give you a view of the code line over time.  You can see who modified what code, when it was inserted or removed from the codeline, etc.

It's not command line though.  I checked briefly in the help and there doesnt' seem to be a way to launch the time lapse view directly from a p4win or p4v invocation.  There might be though...I'll be checking further...

Edit:  I checked with support, and you can launch the timelapse view through p4v as follows:

```
p4v.exe -cmd "annotate //<path/to/file>"
```

HTH.

Comment: I would agree that the TimeLapse view does the job in showing exactly who change what line. Use it all the time.

Comment: How do you launch time lapse view in p4win?

Comment: Even if you use P4Win, you have to install P4V in order have access to the time lapse functionality.  Once you do that, "Time-lapse View..." will appear on the file context menu.

Comment: Howdy. The exact syntax is p4v -cmd "annotate <path_to_file>". The path may either be depot or local.

Comment: note, that p4v timelapse view does _not_ show you merges/integrations. So if a file was copied/integrated from another branch, then time-lapse view doesn't show that history. I just found that out :).

Comment: for future reference: on p4v select a file in worksplace, then right click on that file and you will get "Time-Lapse View" option, just below "revision graph".

Answer (score 6):

I use a small script for blaming

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="$1"
LINE="$2"

p4 annotate -cq "${FILE}" | sed "${LINE}q;d" | cut -f1 -d: | xargs p4 describe -s | sed -e '/Affected files/,$d'
```

you can hook it to some of the editors that will pass the file name and line.

There's a little more complex version [here](https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u/blob/master/p4-annotate).

Answer (score 4):

From the p4v client, you can get "Time-lapse View" context menu on all the view displaying file like Files, Changelist etc.

The time lapse view has quite a few options like Single Revision, Multiple Revision to analyze what was changed, when and by whom.

Answer (score 1):

@alanw123: p4pr is close to what I'm looking for, but it doesn't cross branch boundaries:

```
last if $type eq 'branch';
```

That was the main problem I had when I tried writing my own utility -- you can't (easily) tell how the lines map back to the file that was branched from.

Comment: See post "[New version of p4pr.perl that traces past branchings](http://maillist.perforce.com/pipermail/perforce-user/2000-May/004151.html)". I've changed Alan's answer to use that version since his link is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

The `p4 annotate` command actually *can* follow merges/integrations and branching on the command line with the `-I` and `-i` commands (but it cannot do both at once :( ):

```
-I
Follow integrations into the file. If a line was introduced into the file by a merge, the source of the merge is indicated as the changelist that introduced the line. If that source was itself the result of an integration, that source will be used instead, and so on.
The use of the -I option implies the -c option. The -I option cannot be combined with -i.
-i
Follow file history across branches. If a file was created by branching, Perforce includes revisions up to the branch point.
The use of the -i option implies the -c option. The -i option cannot be combined with -I.
```

Comment: Note that `-I` does follow branches as well, but it does it by a different algorithm (`-i` creates a linearized history following branch records and does a normal annotate on that whereas `-I` follows the entire "tree" across many variants).  The flags are mutually exclusive because the two approaches are not compatible and will yield different results.