# How to make 'p4 annotate' list the modifier name instead of revision number

Tags: perforce

In previous organization, 'cvs annotate' used to give annotation w.r.t modifier login id.
This was very useful and time saving in finding out who modified what in the file.
Could i do same thing in perforce with simple tweeks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question on [SO about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467/perforce-blame) already. The best I can come up with is:

1. Write a python (or ruby or ) wrapper, that calls `p4 annotate -c file`, filters out the change numbers and maps those to users (via `p4 describe -s #change`) and joins the two outputs
2. Use the "Time-lapse View" of p4v

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd write that up quickly and add into eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that [version 2016.2 of `p4` adds a `-u` option to `annotate`](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_annotate.html) that prints the username of the person who modified the line:

> `-u`
>
> Display the name of the user who modified the change and the date when the modification occurred.